# MySQL query get value comma separated from master detail table

Tags: mysql

I've 2 tables in mysql database:

tbl_fruit (fruit_id, fruit_name):

```
fruit id   |   fruit_name
--------------------------
  1        |     Apple  
  2        |     Banana  
  3        |     Mango
```

tbl_order (order_id, order_name, fruit_id):

```
  order_id  |  order_name  | fruit_id 
  ----------------------------------- 
  1         |   John       |   1,2  
  2         |   Matt       |   1,3  
  3         |   Jessica    |   1,2,3
```

expected output :

```
order_name      |  selected_fruit  
----------------------------------
John            |   Apple, Banana  
Matt            |   Apple, Mango  
Jessica         |   Apple, Banana, Mango
```

I've tried some queries but did not match as expected output.
thanks in advance.

SOLVED :

```
SELECT 
  order_name,
  (select 
    GROUP_CONCAT(fruit_name SEPARATOR ', ') 
   from tbl_fruits as fru 
   where
     FIND_IN_SET (fru.fruit_id,ord.fruit_id)) as selected_fruit 
     FROM `tbl_order` as ord
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08eb6f/6/0

Comment: Add the queries you have tried.

Comment: I've done display data by using php, i tried to explode the value and try loop the array base on table fruit. is it possible processing it by mysql query? if it possible i want to make view sql like expected output.

Comment: thanks Hytool, it solved if i create tbl_order_detail which is store row by row fruit selected and use group_concat function. but my question is it possible processing mysql queries or mysql having function like explode? if it can, i can used subquery to getting fruit name.

Comment: @AdityaNursyahbani, I tried it once with sub query, GROUP_CONCAT, FIND_IN_SET etc., but  wasn't succeeded and left it, If you get answer of  that query with SUB QUERY, please post the answer !

Comment: Nooooooooooo. If you're going to do this, then you may as well abandon the RDBMS altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it, but it does not mean that you should. You can join the 2 tables using find_in_set() in a subquery and then use group_concat() in the outer query to get the results back:

```
select t.order_name, group_concat(t.fruit_name) as selected_fruits
from
(select o.order_name, f.fruit_name
from `order` o inner join fruit f on find_in_set(f.fruit_id, o.fruit_id)) t
group by t.order_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query. Use inner query and GROUP_CONCAT both.

```
SELECT order_name,(select GROUP_CONCAT(  fruit_name SEPARATOR  ',' ) from tbl_fruit as fru where FIND_IN_SET (fru.fruit_id,ord.fruit_id)) as selected_fruit FROM `tbl_order` as ord
```

Please try and let me know.

Comment: A subselect for every line?

Comment: @Shadow sorry but can't following you please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You must split the arg before you can use ist for a JOIN. This sample is for max 3 fruits, but you can expand it.

```
SELECT o.order_name, CONCAT_WS(', ', arg1.fruit_name, arg2.fruit_name, arg3.fruit_name ) AS selected_fruit
FROM tbl_order o
LEFT JOIN tbl_fruit arg1 ON arg1.fruit_id = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(o.fruit_id,',,,'),',',1) ,',', -1)
LEFT JOIN tbl_fruit arg2 ON arg2.fruit_id = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(o.fruit_id,',,,'),',',2) ,',', -1)
LEFT JOIN tbl_fruit arg3 ON arg3.fruit_id = SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(o.fruit_id,',,,'),',',3) ,',', -1);
```

**Result**

```
order_name  selected_fruit
John    Apple, Banana
Matt    Apple, Mango
Jessica Apple, Banana, Mango
```

Please let me know if it works

Comment: What if there are more than 3 fruits in an order?

Comment: i wrote it. you must add more left joins. but there is no other solution, or do you know one