# How to INNER JOIN an array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I `INNER JOIN` an array in codeigniter?

I've got two tables, Element and Data:

**TABLE ELEMENT**

```
id |   name   | data
----------------------
1  |  product | 1,5,4
```

**TABLE DATA**

```
id |   name
---------------
1  |  data 1
2  |  data 2
3  |  data 3
4  |  data 4
5  |  data 5
6  |  data 6
```

This is my function:

```
function get($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('
            element.*,
            data.name data_name'
        );

        $this->db->from('elements as element');

        $this->db->join('data_element as data', 'data_name.id = element.data', 'left');

        $this->db->where('id', $id);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

But this return only the first result `data 1` (in this case) from `TABLE ELEMENT` column `data`.

Is it possible combine array with inner join?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query get value comma separated from master detail table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238413/mysql-query-get-value-comma-separated-from-master-detail-table)

Comment: @Strawberry you mean real data into the table?

Comment: @Shadow thank you for the suggest. It's not codeigniter and I don't know if it's possibile to do it.

Comment: @Strawberry ???

Comment: You can only do this in raw sql unless you normalise your data structure.

Comment: @Shadow ok thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with `GROUP_CONCAT(data_element.id) as data_element_id`